# Fill NAs conditional on value

Tags: r, grouping, na, fill

I have a data.frame with a column filled with some NAs, and ids.

```r
x <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, "B", "A", NA, NA, NA, NA, "B", NA, "A")  
id <- rep(1:3, c(8, 6, 2))
df <- data.frame(id = id, x = x)

#    id    x
# 1   1 <NA>
# 2   1 <NA>
# 3   1 <NA>
# 4   1 <NA>
# 5   1    A
# 6   1 <NA>
# 7   1 <NA>
# 8   1    B
# 9   2    A
# 10  2 <NA>
# 11  2 <NA>
# 12  2 <NA>
# 13  2 <NA>
# 14  2    B
# 15  3 <NA>
# 16  3    A
```

I'd like to fill the `x` column by `id`. But the fill should be of different lengths depending on whether `"A"` or `"B"` are being used.

For `"A"`, I'd like the 2 NAs before to be replaced by `"A"`, for `"B"`, the 3 NAs before, so that the expected output should be:

```r
#    id    x
# 1   1 <NA>
# 2   1 <NA>
# 3   1    A
# 4   1    A
# 5   1    A
# 6   1    B
# 7   1    B
# 8   1    B
# 9   2    A
# 10  2 <NA>
# 11  2    B
# 12  2    B
# 13  2    B
# 14  2    B
# 15  3    A
# 16  3    A
```

I use this when I have the same number of NAs to be filled, but I'm not sure how to transpose this into 2 different values depending on `x`. (I tried with ifelse, without success).

```r
setDT(df)[, x := fcoalesce(shift(x, -(0:4))), by = "id"]

#With ifelse?
setDT(df)[, x := ifelse(x == "A", fcoalesce(shift(x, -(0:2))), fcoalesce(shift(x, -(0:1)))), by = "id"]
```

Fast solutions, using `data.table` or `collapse` are preferred. This will be used in a data.frame of over 8M rows and 100K groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, x := fifelse(fcoalesce(shift(x, -(0:3))) == "B", "B", fcoalesce(shift(x, -(0:2)))), by = "id"][]

    id    x
 1:  1 <NA>
 2:  1 <NA>
 3:  1    A
 4:  1    A
 5:  1    A
 6:  1    B
 7:  1    B
 8:  1    B
 9:  2    A
10:  2 <NA>
11:  2    B
12:  2    B
13:  2    B
14:  2    B
15:  3    A
16:  3    A
```

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to use `vctrs::vec_fill_missing()` as it has a pretty small overhead and is pretty memory efficient, at least from the limited tests I've done, though I may be way off mark.

```
library(vctrs)
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, xa := fifelse(x == "A", "A", NA_character_)]
df[, xb := fifelse(x == "B", "B", NA_character_)]

vec_fill2 <- function(x){
  vec_fill_missing(x, direction = "up", max_fill = 2L)
}
vec_fill3 <- function(x){
  vec_fill_missing(x, direction = "up", max_fill = 3L)
}

df[, c("xa", "xb") := list(xa = vec_fill2(xa),
                           xb = vec_fill3(xb)),
   by = id]
df[, x := fcoalesce(x, xa, xb)]
df
> df
    id    x   xa   xb
 1:  1 <NA> <NA> <NA>
 2:  1 <NA> <NA> <NA>
 3:  1    A    A <NA>
 4:  1    A    A <NA>
 5:  1    A    A    B
 6:  1    B <NA>    B
 7:  1    B <NA>    B
 8:  1    B <NA>    B
 9:  2    A    A <NA>
10:  2 <NA> <NA> <NA>
11:  2    B <NA>    B
12:  2    B <NA>    B
13:  2    B <NA>    B
14:  2    B <NA>    B
15:  3    A    A <NA>
16:  3    A    A <NA>
```

I also have a `collapse` solution for a grouped rolling `NA` fill that might be fast but is not very memory efficient at the moment.